# Nested includes with where on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Lets say we have 3 tables:

```
products (title, product_type_id)
product_types (title)
product_type_options (product_type_id, size)
```

I want to load product, its type & ONLY specific product_type_options (`product_type_options.size = 'XL'`)

Is it possible to do without N+1 query in rails?

Something like:

```
Product.includes( product_type: [product_type_options] )
       .where("product_type_options.size = 'XL'")
```

I can not it get it to work with `where` parameter. Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

This should work

```
Product.includes(product_type: :product_type_options)
  .where(product_types: { product_type_options: { size: 'XL' } })
```

Answer (score 3):

@Iceman was close... the reason it's not seeing 'product_types' is because it needs to be represented as an explicit hash inside the where clause, then Ruby will do the proper nesting...

```
Product.includes(product_type: :product_type_options)
  .where({ product_types: { product_type_options: { size: 'XL' } } })
```

Strange, but adding the extra **{}** in the where clause makes the nested includes work.

Answer (score -3):

Please try this, this is a small syntax change. I have not tested it. Let me know if it works :)

```
Product.includes( product_type: [product_type_options] )
   .where("product_type_options.size" => 'XL')
```

Comment: The answer was the example from the question. Which hasn't worked then. Please improve your answer or consider deleting it.

Comment: My answer is improvement or a fix to the problem asked. Please see the change I have made. Anyone can infer from the change to resolve his own version of problem similar to this post's.